# module with classes with only static methods

Tags: python, class, design-patterns, static-methods

I have a Python module that contains a number of classes, each representing a particular physical material with its properties (e.g., density, specific heat). Some of the properties are just `float` members of the class, but many depend on some parameter, e.g., the temperature. I implemented this through `@staticmethod`s, i.e., all of the classes look like

```py
class Copper:
    magnetic_permeability = 1.0

    @staticmethod
    def density(T):
        return 1.0 / (-3.033e-9 + 68.85e-12*T - 6.72e-15*T**2 + 8.56e-18*T**3)

    @staticmethod
    def electric_conductivity(T, p):
        return 1.0141 * T**2 * p

    @staticmethod
    def specific heat(T):
        return # ...


class Silver:
    # ...

class Argon:
    # ...

# ...
```

The `Class`es thus merely act as containers for all the data, and the abundance of `@staticmethod`s has me suspecting that there may be a more appropriate design pattern for this use case.

Any hints?

Comment: If it's static... that means that it's basically fixed values. If so, it's really data, and might be better handled as more traditional data structure. dictionary if you want to create it live, something like xml/yaml if you want to load if from disk. i even wrote a set of classes once that would load an XML and expose it as attributes, so you could still do things like `metals.copper.magnetic_permeability * 4` even though `metals` was loaded from an XML. something like that might give you the best of both worlds...

Comment: But the properties are dependant on temperature etc.

Comment: staticmethod actually seems quite appropriate.

Comment: Do all the densities depend on  `1.0 / (a + b*T - c*T**2 + d*T**3)`, all the electric conductivities on `a * T**2 * p`, all the magnetic permeabilities constant, etc?

Comment: @MikeGraham No. The relationships get more complex and vary across the materials.

Comment: Usually, if you have a class at all, it's because you need to maintain some state.  If your class is just staticmethods, then they're really just a bunch of functions and you're using the class to "namespace" the functions.  It's a bit code smelly in my opinion, not the pythonic way to do namespacing.

Comment: Sounds like it is okay for a class to have only static methods see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942903/is-it-bad-practice-for-a-class-to-have-only-static-fields-and-methods)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could name your module `copper` and create all of these as module level functions, then `import copper; copper.density(0)`.

But what if someone does `from copper import density`, and you also have a module called `cobalt` and another called `carbon` and another called `chlorine` etc., all with their own `density` functions? Uh oh.

Since [we're all consenting adults here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html), you can document this and expect your users to know well enough to import just the module. Or you can take your approach; in this case, I would consider putting all of your elements in one module called `elements`, then the user can `from elements import Copper`. Static methods would then be appropriate.

Comment: Actually, cannot the `__all__` module-level variable help users not importing stuff improperly ?

Comment: @CédricVanRompay I don't think I see how `__all__` would prevent people from shadowing stuff when importing. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that a more fitting structure would be to have a `Material` class, which takes either functions or coefficients as arguments, e.g.

```
class Material(object):

    def __init__(self, mag_perm, density_coeffs, ...):
        self.mag_perm = mag_perm
        self._density_coeffs = density_coeffs
        ...

    def density(self, T):
        x0, x1, x2, x3 = self._density_coeffs
        return 1.0 / (x0 + (x1 * T) + (x2 * (T ** 2)) + (x3 * (T ** 3)))
```

Each material then supplies its own coefficients for each calculated parameter:

```
copper = Material(1.0, (-3.033e-9, 68.85e-12, 6.72e-15, 8.56e-18), ...)
copper.density(300)
```

If you need more complex relationships (e.g. different calculations) you could use sub-classes of `Material` and over-load the appropriate calculations.

Comment: Good - levelling up in the abstraction is appropriate here.

Comment: Having a method called `density` when you pass in a variable also called `density` to `__init__` (which is really a tuple of coefficients used in some calculation of the density), is kind of an insane interface though!

Comment: @MikeGraham that's not the issue -- the problem is that density was not a sensible name for the tuple of four coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a "season to taste" question. You could do as you've done -- methods on a class OR you could eliminate the class entirely, and just go with module level functions.  In general, I prefer whichever is simpler to read/understand & maintain.

Based strictly on the limited example you shared -- I lean towards module level functions. But of course, a more fleshed out example might alter that opinion.

Comment: The code example should now give a more complete understanding of what the file contents are.

Answer (score 2):

How about making the variable properties functions that take all required values as arguments?

```
def density(T):
    <some function of T>

def electrical_conductivity(T, p):
    <some function of T and p>

def some_other_property(T, magnetic_permeability):
    <some function of T and magnetic permeability>
```

Then, the fixed properties could be defined through a dictionary.

```
copper_fixed_properties = {'magnetic_permeability': 1, ...}
```

You would use this in the following way:

```
copper_some_other_property = some_other_property(T, copper.magnetic_permeability)
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining a staticmethod is virtually always a mistake. Python has functions, so you'd always just define a module-level function. (You'd have `copper.py` and inside of it have a plain old `def density(T):` instead of using a staticmethod.)

That is to say, `copper.py` would look like

```
magnetic_permeability = 1.0

def density(T):
    return 1.0 / (-3.033e-9 + 68.85e-12*T - 6.72e-15*T**2 + 8.56e-18*T**3)

def electric_conductivity(T, p):
    return 1.0141 * T**2 * p

def specific heat(T):
    return ...
```

---

In this particular case, do you actually have multiple materials? If so, then you probably want them to be instances, not classes or modules. If you e.g., don't want them all to have the same rational cubic form for the thermal density dependence, you can make a subclass and have an instance of that or you can make a class that accepts functions as arguments.

```
class Material(object):
    def __init__(self, density, electric conductivity):
        self.density = density
        self.electric_conductivity = electric_conductivity

copper = Material(
    density=lambda T: 1.0 / (-3.033e-9 + 68.85e-12*T - 
                             6.72e-15*T**2 + 8.56e-18*T**3),
    electric_conductivity=lambda T, p: 1.0141 * T**2 * p
)
```

You can also make a metaclass if you want to maintain a declarative style.

---

By the way

```
class Copper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.magnetic_permeability = 1.0
    ...
```

probably doesn't do what you want to. This makes `magnetic_permeability` only accessible in an *instance* of `copper`. I *don't recommend using classes rather than instances or modules for this*, but if you did, you'd need to do

```
class Copper(object):
    magnetic_permeability = 1.0
    ...
```

to be able to do `Copper.magnetic_permeability`

---

Note that I'm inheriting with object so that we're using Python 2 "new style classes". The changes are subtle, but it's nicer if you just ensure you'll never run into them.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about `object`. I corrected the example in the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

While agreeing the other answers, here's a decorator that makes all methods of the decorated class a staticmethod:

```
import types

def staticclass(cls):
    for fname, f in cls.__dict__.items():
        if isinstance(f, types.FunctionType):
           setattr(cls, fname, staticmethod(f))
    return cls
```

Usage example:

```
@staticclass
class Copper:
    magnetic_permeability = 1.0

    def density(T):
        return 1.0 / (-3.033e-9 + 68.85e-12*T - 6.72e-15*T**2 + 8.56e-18*T**3)

    def electric_conductivity(T, p):
        return 1.0141 * T**2 * p

    def specific_heat(T):
        return # ...
```